# Extra empty alternate rows in my html table

Tags: html, html-table, rows

Making a simple table and I noticed something odd when I was trying to do something with alternate rows and javascript and it did not work. When I looked at the page in inspector in Firefox and Chrome I noticed extra rows  between each one of my rows. It even does it when I just have the table with no CSS or JS.

I can work around this it's not not a problem I am just wondering why they are there?

This is my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
     <head>
          <meta charset=utf-8>
          <title>table test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>title 01</th>
              <th>title 02</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>thing 01</td>
              <td>attribute 01</td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
              <td>thing 02</td>
              <td>attribute 02</td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
              <td>thing 03</td>
              <td>attribute 03</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

This is what the code looks like in Firefox inspector:

[image: This is what the code looks like in Firefox inspector]

Answer (score 1):

On the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows you're using an opening `<tr>` where you should be using a closing `</tr>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
     <head>
          <meta charset=utf-8>
          <title>table test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>title 01</th>
              <th>title 02</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>thing 01</td>
              <td>attribute 01</td>
            </tr> <!-- CHANGED TO CLOSING </tr> -->
            <tr>
              <td>thing 02</td>
              <td>attribute 02</td>
            </tr> <!-- CHANGED TO CLOSING </tr> -->
            <tr>
              <td>thing 03</td>
              <td>attribute 03</td>
            </tr> <!-- CHANGED TO CLOSING </tr> -->
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @APAD1 Don't I feel stupid. The original table is was generated by a loop so that's why it's not on the header row!

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us!